# Why are network routes asymmetric

Tags: networking, routes

I have a generel question on netowrks. I wanted to know why a route from A to B is different from B to A. Why aren't they symmetric always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they depend on how the route table is configured in each individual router or device it pass through from source to target locations.

Given this network:

```
A - B - C
    | /
    D
```

A message can go from A to D by traveling through B (`A-B-D`) But maybe D is configured to every outgoing packets be routed through C so the return path can be (`D-C-B-A`).

Probably not the best example but I think it makes a point. *Every* router is in charge of building and maintain their local `route tables` so this kind of situations can happen. You can find more information on [Wikipedia page for Routing Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_table).

Hope this helps!

Comment: But why would someone configure D to route packets to A through C?

Comment: It could be possible. Maybe the example ain't good enough but that actually happens in reality. Consider than the whole internet is larger than only 4 devices, though keeping every route table optimal is a hard work.